# When install an app on a windows mobile device, install prerequisites

Tags: .net, deployment, windows-mobile

Is it possible when installing an app on a windows mobile device to automatically install the compact framework, the sql ce compact, etc ?

Or those can only be installed manually?

Answer (score 0):

Is it your own app? If it's someone else's app they should have included the prerequisites in their installer. If they haven't you have to find the prerequisites yourself and install them manually.

If it's your own app you can build a Smart Device Project and include the cabs that you need for your app to run.
Here is a tutorial on how to build a Smart Device Project.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcebx8f8(v=VS.90).aspx